# Inline paragraph in Trello comment

Tags: trello, trello-cards

How can I insert an inline paragraph in Trello comments like the screenshot below?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The screenshot actually shows a code block

Code block - Include formatted code by wrapping it in three backticks (```) at the beginning and end of the block, or by starting a line with four spaces. Note that the triple backticks have to be on a separate line and ensure you have a blank line before and after the code block.

Inline code - Include inline formatted code by wrapping it in a single backtick (`) at the beginning and end of the code.

You can find more on styling here: http://help.trello.com/article/821-using-markdown-in-trello

Apart from that, comments are always displayed chronologically